# What is the best way to fetch data in core data between two regular view controllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Sorry if the title is bad. What I'm trying to understand is: in the core data examples I have found online they explain how to use core data with nsfetchresultcontroller. But from what I understand nsfetchresultcontroller is made for table views.  But I have only 2 regular view controllers.

It's really basic, I have 1 view controller for a create page to create a task, and another one which is the homepage with a label to show that single task that was created:

HomePageViewController.m:

```
#import "HomePageViewController.h"
#import "CreatTargetViewController.h"

@interface HomePageViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *currentTarget;

@end

@implementation HomePageViewController


- (IBAction)unwindToHomePage:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{

    CreatTargetViewController *source = (CreatTargetViewController *)[segue sourceViewController];

    self.currentTarget.text = source.target.content;

}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

CreatTargetViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Targets.h"

@interface CreatTargetViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) Targets *target;


@end
```

CreatTargetViewController.m:

```
#import "CreatTargetViewController.h"
#import "Targets.h"
#import "CoreDataStack.h"

@interface CreatTargetViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *saveButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *myTextView;

@end

@implementation CreatTargetViewController


- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if (sender != self.saveButton) return;
    if (self.target != nil) {
        self.myTextView.text = self.target.content;
    }
}

- (void)insertNewTargetEntry
{
    CoreDataStack *coreDataStack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];

    Targets *entry = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Targets" inManagedObjectContext:coreDataStack.managedObjectContext];

    entry.content = self.myTextView.text;

    [coreDataStack saveContext];

}

- (void)updateTargetEntry
{
    self.target.content = self.myTextView.text;

    CoreDataStack *stack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];

    [stack saveContext];
}

- (IBAction)saveWasPressed:(id)sender
{
    if (self.target != nil) {
        [self updateTargetEntry];
    } else {
        [self insertNewTargetEntry];
    }
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.myTextView becomeFirstResponder];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

and another class for the core data stack:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface CoreDataStack : NSObject

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;


+ (instancetype)defaultStack;
- (void)saveContext;
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;

@end
```

CoreDataStack.m:

```
#import "CoreDataStack.h"

@implementation CoreDataStack

#pragma mark - Core Data stack

@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;


+ (instancetype)defaultStack
{
    static CoreDataStack *defaultStack;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once (&onceToken, ^{
        defaultStack = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return defaultStack;
}

- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "digitalCrown.LaserApp" in the application's documents directory.
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}

- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
    // The managed object model for the application. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"LaserApp" withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it.
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    // Create the coordinator and store

    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"LaserApp.sqlite"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *failureReason = @"There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data.";
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
        // Report any error we got.
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = @"Failed to initialize the application's saved data";
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason;
        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error;
        error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN" code:9999 userInfo:dict];
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}


- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.)
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (!coordinator) {
        return nil;
    }
    _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    return _managedObjectContext;
}

#pragma mark - Core Data Saving support

- (void)saveContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }
}
```

How do I communicate the data here?

Comment: You're trying to fetch the inserted data and pass it back to your next UIViewController?

Comment: Are you asking how to do a fetch? If so, create a fetchRequest object (with 
fetchRequestWithEntityName:) and call 
executeFetchRequest:error: on your managed object context.

Comment: yes, exactly  @staaar

Comment: "But from what I understand nsfetchresultcontroller is made for table views". Nope, it's a controller that manages a set of results for a fetch request. You can use it with things other than table views. This has advantages over using `executeRequest`. A fetched results controller observes the context for changes relevant to it's fetch request, so it sees updates/inserts/changes as they happen and magically updates.